# SQL Azure and CakePHP

Tags: sql, cakephp, comparison, azure

Has anyone connected CakePHP to SQL Azure? Google doesn't come up with anything. I am finding more examples of RoR connecting to SQL Azure actually, so given that Azure is relatively new, does this mean RoR is evolving faster than CakePHP? Having read numerous comparisons between the two frameworks, I have yet to settle on one, so maybe a better understanding here will tip the balance. Please assume my learning-curve is equal for both.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement and add DataSources for CakePHP to connect to databases not already defined.

There also is an existing DataSource for Azure available [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Howard/2010/02/02/microsoft-windows-azure-tables-datasource).